# Format date time for mysql data type timesstamp

Tags: javascript, mysql

I'm trying to store 05/09/2014 11:57 am into MySQL timestamp data type and it's putting in null or '0000-00-00 00:00:00' into the database. I want to store something like 05/09/2014 11:57 am. I'm using this, http://www.jqueryrain.com/?lnsG0UbP, datepicker to get my date and time. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What are you using to connect the Javascript to MySQL? I'd imagine there's *something* in between (whether that's PHP, .NET, Java or something else.) In general you shouldn't be formatting the data at all - you should be passing it straight to the database in the native format for a MySQL timestamp, which is something the driver should handle for you.

Comment: I figured that it has to be in 'Y-m-d H:i:s' format but I want to display 'm/d/Y g:i a' for user but when the user submits, it uses 'Y-m-d H:i:s' instead? I'm using PHP. How do I convert the current display date time on the fly during submit? Thanks!

Comment: Again, you shouldn't need to format the value at all - the PHP driver should be able to pass it *as a timestamp*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to format your date accordingly. For reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html

Did you use the date() and strtotime() function?

Comment: While you *can* format it, I generally dislike this approach. String conversions should be avoided where possible. I'd *expect* a PHP MySQL driver to be able to take the timestamp value itself as whatever type of object PHP uses for this sort of thing. Let the *driver* format it if it really needs to, and otherwise the native internal format...

Comment: Thanks! I guess my original question was answered. I can't store the way I have it formatted. My issue is, I want to convert the display date time (for users) to the correct format store mysql when the user submits.